# How to remove the first element from the array flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a StreamBuilder to get snapShot from my FB backend as an list. But I am trying to remove the first element from that list How can I do that?

code:

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot?>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(userUid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //SnapShot
          var rooms = snapshot.data?['room'];
          List<dynamic> room = rooms;
          return...

         //Action to remove 0
       ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async => {
                      //Remove the first string in this array
                      room.removeAt(0)},
                   
                    child: const Text('Remove first element from array'),
                  ),
```

Error: `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`

Img: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `firebase` doesn't support deleting by `index`.

The preferred approach would be:

Create a new subcollection `room` and there you add documents which were primarily array elements.

Then you could delete like so:

```
db.collection('users')
.doc(currentUser.uid)
.collection('room')
.doc(<room1-docId>) //  To delte room 1
.delete()
```

Note: `Error Null is not subtype of type List<dynamic>` is caused by

```
List<dynamic> room = rooms; // rooms are possibly Null , because of which you are getting the error.
```